# Unable to get what I need since I'm new to Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve simple layout structure with Flexbox. I'm referring [Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and learning on my own. Below is my code and what I'm trying to achieve.

```css
.order-history-items {
  .order-history-table {
    
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    li {
      list-style-position: inside;
      list-style-type: square;
    }
    .order-shipped-to,
    .order-items,
    .order-total-price {
      width: 33%;
    }
    .toggle {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
.js .order-history-table .hidden {
  display: none;
}




   

    .orderdetails {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      
      // margin: 0 1%;

      h1 {
        flex-basis: 100%;
      }

      h2 {
        clear: both;
        flex-basis: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .label {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: .3rem;
        margin-top: .3rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
      .order-shipment-table {
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid ;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 1em;
      }
      .order-shipment-details {
        .order-shipment-address {
          float: right;
        }
      }
      .line-items {
        clear: both;
        padding-top: 1rem;
        .line-item {
          padding-bottom: 1rem;
          .line-item-details,
          .line-item-quantity,
          .line-item-price {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
          }
          .line-item-quantity,
          .line-item-price {
            width: 14%;
          }
          .line-item-details {
            width: 70%;
            a {
              font-size: 1.1rem;
            }
          }
          .line-item-quantity {
            text-align: center;
          }
          .line-item-price {
            text-align: right;
          }
        }
      }
        flex-basis: 25%;
        .order-payment-summary {
        @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
          float: right;
        }
        .label {
          font-weight: 800;
          font-size: 15px;
          margin-bottom: 12px;
        }
        .order-detail-summary {
          .order-key {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #000;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            font-size: 12px;
          }
          .order-value.number--smallest {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: 0px;
            color: #000;
          }
          .order-value.number--large {
            color: #000;
            letter-spacing: 0;
          }
        }
      }
      .order-information {
        flex-basis: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        // padding-bottom: .5em;
        // padding-top: .5em;
        .order-status {
          span {
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 800;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: smaller;
          }
        }
        .order-date {
          span {
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 800;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: smaller;
          }
        }
        .label {
          color: white;
          font-weight: 300;
          text-transform: none;
        }
        .value {
          font-weight: 700;
        }
        .order-number {
          font-size: 1.75rem;
        }
      }
      .payment-amount {
        .label {
          font-weight: normal;
          text-transform: none;
        }
      }
      .order-totals-table td {
        &:first-child {
          padding-right: 5rem;
          text-align: left;
        }
      }
      .order-payment-instruments,
      .order-billing,
      .order-shipment-address
      {
        flex-basis: 25%;
        .label {
          font-weight: 800;
          font-size: 15px;
        }
      }
      .order-payment-instruments{
        padding-left: 84px;
      }
      .order-billing {
        padding-left: 100px;
      }
      .order-shipment-address
      {
          padding-left: 120px;
      }
      .order-shipments {
        h2 {
          display: flex;
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="orderdetails">
  <h1>My Order</h1>
  <h2 class="order-number">
    <span class="label">Order :</span>
    <span class="value">STG00004302</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="order-information">
    <div class="order-status">
      <span class="label">Order Status:</span>
      <span class="value clearfix">Complete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="order-date">
      <span class="label">Order Placed:</span>
      <span class="value">10/27/2017 11:02:15 AM</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-payment-summary">
    <div class="label">Payment Total</div>
    <div class="order-detail-summary">
      <div class="order-totals-table">
        <div class="order-subtotal order-row">
          <div class="order-key">Subtotal</div>
          <div class="order-value number--smallest">C$ 21.33</div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-shipping order-row">
          <div class="order-key">
            Shipping
          </div>
          <div class="order-value number--smallest">
            C$ 0.00
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-sales-tax order-row">
          <div class="order-key">Taxes</div>
          <div class="order-value number--smallest">
            C$ 2.77
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-total order-row">
          <div class="order-key">Order Total:</div>
          <div class="order-value number--large">C$ 24.10</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-payment-instruments">
    <div class="label">
      Payment Method
    </div>
    <div class="payment-type">PayPal</div>
    <div class="payment-amount">
      <span class="label">Amount:</span>
      <span class="value">C$ 24.10</span>
    </div>
    <!-- END: payment-amount -->
  </div>
  <div class="order-billing">
    <div class="label">Billing Address</div>
    <div class="mini-address-name">
      Dhon Rocafort
    </div>
    <div class="mini-address-location">
      <address>
        1120 N St
        <br>Sacramento,
        CA
        95814-5680<br>
        United States
        <br>
        2122121423
      </address>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-shipment-address">
    <div class="label">Shipping To</div>
    <div class="mini-address-name">
      DihonsKi Rocafort
    </div>
    <div class="mini-address-location">
      <address>
        Air Canada Centre
        <br>40 Bay St
        <br>Toronto,
        ON
        M5J 2X2<br>
        Canada
        <br>
        2122121423
      </address>
    </div>
    <div class="shipping-method">
      <div class="label">Method:</div>
      <div class="value">StandardCA</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should look like [this](https://img2.brain3.photobox.com/632333070e56509131d37c5d5598ae6b6fbde53cff14bb040e534143bb5e77eda3a37eea.jpg) in desktop view :

I'm caring about the main 4 columns in the end of the image, it should be responsive too. I don't have any specifics for the mobile view, but those 4 columns should be 2*2 in mobile view.

Comment: I'm guessing I should not give so many <br> tags in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** OPEN THE SNIPPET IN FULL PAGE.

Now, first off please try to add as minimal code as possible because it's way too hard to go through this long HTML, you could remove extra tags and labels since all you need to know is how to align using `flex`.

I just adjusted the alignments to match the screenshot you posted. I added all the CSS properties as inline styles with `style` attribute on the respective tags.

Everything you need about Flexboxes will be here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. Try them out and you will get a hang of it very easily.

**TIP** Breakdown your webpage into components and wrap them in `divs`. It will be much easier to control alignments with this setup particularly with `flexboxes`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.order-history-items {
  .order-history-table {
    
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    li {
      list-style-position: inside;
      list-style-type: square;
    }
    .order-shipped-to,
    .order-items,
    .order-total-price {
      width: 33%;
    }
    .toggle {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
.js .order-history-table .hidden {
  display: none;
}




   

    .orderdetails {
      display: flex;
      
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      
      // margin: 0 1%;

      h1 {
        flex-basis: 100%;
      }

      h2 {
        clear: both;
        flex-basis: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .label {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: .3rem;
        margin-top: .3rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
      .order-shipment-table {
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid ;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 1em;
      }
      .order-shipment-details {
        .order-shipment-address {
          float: right;
        }
      }
      .line-items {
        clear: both;
        padding-top: 1rem;
        .line-item {
          padding-bottom: 1rem;
          .line-item-details,
          .line-item-quantity,
          .line-item-price {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
          }
          .line-item-quantity,
          .line-item-price {
            width: 14%;
          }
          .line-item-details {
            width: 70%;
            a {
              font-size: 1.1rem;
            }
          }
          .line-item-quantity {
            text-align: center;
          }
          .line-item-price {
            text-align: right;
          }
        }
      }
        flex-basis: 25%;
        .order-payment-summary {
        @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
          float: right;
        }
        .label {
          font-weight: 800;
          font-size: 15px;
          margin-bottom: 12px;
        }
        .order-detail-summary {
          .order-key {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #000;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            font-size: 12px;
          }
          .order-value.number--smallest {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: 0px;
            color: #000;
          }
          .order-value.number--large {
            color: #000;
            letter-spacing: 0;
          }
        }
      }
      .order-information {
        flex-basis: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        // padding-bottom: .5em;
        // padding-top: .5em;
        .order-status {
          span {
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 800;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: smaller;
          }
        }
        .order-date {
          span {
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 800;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: smaller;
          }
        }
        .label {
          color: white;
          font-weight: 300;
          text-transform: none;
        }
        .value {
          font-weight: 700;
        }
        .order-number {
          font-size: 1.75rem;
        }
      }
      .payment-amount {
        .label {
          font-weight: normal;
          text-transform: none;
        }
      }
      .order-totals-table td {
        &:first-child {
          padding-right: 5rem;
          text-align: left;
        }
      }
      .order-payment-instruments,
      .order-billing,
      .order-shipment-address
      {
        flex-basis: 25%;
        .label {
          font-weight: 800;
          font-size: 15px;
        }
      }
      .order-payment-instruments{
        padding-left: 84px;
      }
      .order-billing {
        padding-left: 100px;
      }
      .order-shipment-address
      {
          padding-left: 120px;
      }
      .order-shipments {
        h2 {
          display: flex;
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="orderdetails" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 50%">
  <h1 style="margin: auto;">My Order</h1>
  <h2 class="order-number" style="margin: auto;">
    <span class="label">Order :</span>
    <span class="value">STG00004302</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="order-information" style="margin: 10px;">
    <div class="order-status">
      <span class="label">Order Status:</span>
      <span class="value clearfix">Complete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="order-date">
      <span class="label">Order Placed:</span>
      <span class="value">10/27/2017 11:02:15 AM</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around;">
    <div class="order-payment-summary">
      <div class="label">Payment Total</div>
      <div class="order-detail-summary">
        <div class="order-totals-table">
          <div class="order-subtotal order-row">
            <div class="order-key">Subtotal</div>
            <div class="order-value number--smallest">C$ 21.33</div>
          </div>
          <div class="order-shipping order-row">
            <div class="order-key">
              Shipping
            </div>
            <div class="order-value number--smallest">
              C$ 0.00
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="order-sales-tax order-row">
            <div class="order-key">Taxes</div>
            <div class="order-value number--smallest">
              C$ 2.77
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="order-total order-row">
            <div class="order-key">Order Total:</div>
            <div class="order-value number--large">C$ 24.10</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-payment-instruments">
      <div class="label">
        Payment Method
      </div>
      <div class="payment-type">PayPal</div>
      <div class="payment-amount">
        <span class="label">Amount:</span>
        <span class="value">C$ 24.10</span>
      </div>
      <!-- END: payment-amount -->
    </div>
    <div class="order-billing">
      <div class="label">Billing Address</div>
      <div class="mini-address-name">
        Dhon Rocafort
      </div>
      <div class="mini-address-location">
        <address>
          1120 N St
          <br>Sacramento,
          CA
          95814-5680<br>
          United States
          <br>
          2122121423
        </address>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-shipment-address">
      <div class="label">Shipping To</div>
      <div class="mini-address-name">
        DihonsKi Rocafort
      </div>
      <div class="mini-address-location">
        <address>
          Air Canada Centre
          <br>40 Bay St
          <br>Toronto,
          ON
          M5J 2X2<br>
          Canada
          <br>
          2122121423
        </address>
      </div>
      <div class="shipping-method">
        <div class="label">Method:</div>
        <div class="value">StandardCA</div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All the child divs are in same row. I wanted only last 4 columns in 1 row. Others you can ignore

Comment: Which is why I asked you to open the code snippet in full page. Check it out in full page, I am not sure why the preview here is like this.

Answer (score 0):

[**CHECK THIS CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/RjxMWO?editors=1100)

The code is cluttered, but I have used Flexbox for your Payment total and `position:absolute` to your  `class="order-value"` and `right:10px`

Comment: It was working before, just check the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/RjxMWO?editors=1100) I have corrected the CSS code..